# Swift tableView cell subviews flicker (disappear and then reappear) when cell is selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a viewCell with a few different subviews. one of them is a label with an orange background. now when I select the cell in the tableview the label background flicker(disappear and then reappear) to its original i cant see what is causing this issue.

```
//my did select func
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
//        let selectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        let post = RquestInfoArray[indexPath.row]
        if post["status"] as! String == "pending" {

            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "My Rquest", message: "Options", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
            let detailAction = UIAlertAction(title: "View Detail", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
                print("view detail pressed")
            })
            let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                print("Delete")
            })
            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
            })

            ac.addAction(detailAction)
            ac.addAction(deleteAction)
            ac.addAction(cancelAction)
            self.present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return
        }

        if post["status"] as! String == "accepted" {
            let vc = messageViewController()
            let posting = RquestInfoArray[indexPath.row]
            let postId = posting["rquestId"] as! String
            vc.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
            vc.postId = postId

            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have a Custom Cell class with the label with an orange background (lets call it `MyTableViewCell`).

So you have to override the [`setHighlighted(_:animated:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623280-sethighlighted) function for that cell, and keep the label's background to orange.

```
override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    ...
    label.backgroundColor = <YourOrange>
}
```

You may need to override [`setSelected(_:animated:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623255-setselected) depending on your code.

You can also just set the cell's [`UITableViewCellSelectionStyle` to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UITableViewCellSelectionStyle) instead.